# Querying entries that have not been related to any other entry or contained matrix element

Tags: entries, matrix, relations

I have a large amount of content that we are attempting to collect before we migrate to our new site structures. Normally the staff are supposed to relate content *back* to main entries to make sure that content ownership is maintained as seen below.

[image: Screenshot of relationships on a child entry]

However, they often would just add a page and then add a link to a relationship from a parent page as they discovered this was "easier":

[image: Screenshot of entries that are being selected for display on a parent page]

What I’m wondering is if there is a way for me to query entries that have not been related in the second method. The first example is simple, for example, I can query my topics that are missing relationship fields filled out like so:

```
{% set total = 
  craft.entries.section("topics")
    .departments(":empty:")
    .boardsCommissions(":empty:")
    .officials(":empty:")
    .processes(":empty:")
    .projects(":empty:")
    .topics(":empty:")
 %}
<h1>Topics missing all relationship fields: {{ total | length }}</h1>
{% for entry in total.all() %}
  {{ entry.title }} - {{ entry.author }} - {{ entry.id }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Where I’m getting confused is how I would query the second example, as what I want to do is query if the entries have been related to *any other content on the site*, **which also includes matrix fields** that may also have those relationships, instead of predefined fields.